# Надо выбрать самую дешевую скидку

Tags: java, selenium

.Такое вот задание надо  на сайте https://www.slivki.by/sushi-2  выбрать суши с самой большой скидкой. Покажите что я неправильно написал? Вот мой неудачный код.

```
  public class Firstcase {
    @Test
    public void test2() {
        FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.slivki.by/sushi-2");
        List<WebElement> discont = driver.findElements(By.className("discount-label"));
        List<WebElement> sortedDiscont = driver.findElements(By.className("discount-label"));
        Collections.sort(sortedDiscont, comparator);
        System.out.println(sortedDiscont.get(0).getText() + " index= " + discont.indexOf(sortedDiscont.get(0)));discont.get(discont.indexOf(sortedDiscont.get(0))).click();
      int k=discont.indexOf(sortedDiscont.get(0));
     String sw=Integer.toString(k);
   String Str="//img[contains(@src,'http://store.akamai.steamstatic.com/public/images/blank.gif')])[30]";
      String fin=Str.replace("30", sw);
      System.out.println(fin);
     // driver.findElementByXPath(fin);
        for (WebElement element : discont) {
            System.out.println(element.getText() + "\n");
        }
        discont.get(discont.indexOf(sortedDiscont.get(0))).click();
        driver.quit();
    }


Comparator<WebElement> comparator = new Comparator<WebElement>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(WebElement o1, WebElement o2) {
        int firstValue = 0;
        int secondValue = 0;
        try {
            firstValue = Integer.parseInt(o1.getText().replace("%", "").replace("-", ""));
            secondValue = Integer.parseInt(o2.getText().replace("%", "").replace("-", ""));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (firstValue == 0 && secondValue == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        return firstValue > secondValue ? -1 : 1;
    }
};}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно пойти другим путем, после того как мы нашли элемент с самой большой скидкой берем его родителя и у него уже ищем элемент с тегом img:

```
WebElement result= discont.get(0).findElement(By.xpath("..//img"));
result.click();
```

Советую вам изучить XPath, это как регулярки для разбора строк, имеет мощный механизм поиска.